# Floating point overflow. Can this power equation be simplified?

Tags: exponentiation, floating-point

I’m running into trouble with the following formula that we’re using in our software.

$$
\frac{1 - x^{-y}}{1 - x^{-(y+1)}}
$$

In certain cases, the value for $y$ is a relatively large number; sometimes positive, sometimes negative. I just had a case where its value was `-13729.03476`. Since I’m using ‘regular’ double-precision variables, this led to a floating point overflow error.

Looking at it, I get the distinct impression that it should be possible to simplify this formula, but I just can’t figure out how.

Alternatively, is there some other way to prevent (or predict) a floating point overflow in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What values can $x$ have? If $x$ can be $1$ or $\le 0$, then the expression is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually very simple. If $x > 1$ and $y$ is positive, or if $x < 1$ and $y$ is negative, then $x^y$ can blow up, so you use the original expression

$$\frac{1 - x^{-y}}{1 - x^{-(y+1)}}$$

If $x > 1$ and $y$ is negative, or if $x < 1$ and $y$ is positive, then $x^{-y}$ can blow up, so you use the expression

$$\frac{x(x^y -1)}{x^{y+1} - 1}$$

But if $x = 1$, then the expression is undefined. I don't know if this can happen in your software, but if so, you need to figure out some way of handling it!

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I spent over an hour trying to wrap my math-impaired brain around this. I had already taken care of the $x = 1$ and $x \le 0$ scenarios, so those should not occur.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: i would say this is simplified $$\frac{x \left(x^y-1\right)}{x^{y+1}-1}$$

Comment: Unfortunately this expression can blow up if $y$ is large and positive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate form (courtesy of [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-x%5E%28-y%29%29%2F%281-x%5E%28-%28y%2B1%29%29%29)):

$$\frac{x(x^y -1)}{x^{y+1} - 1}. $$

I'm not sure, however, if that helps your overflow.

What may help your overflow is to look at
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x(x^y-1)}{x^{y+1}-1}\right| &= 
\exp\left( \ln\left(\left|\frac{x(x^y-1)}{x^{y+1}-1}\right|\right)\right) \\
&=\exp\left(\ln|x(x^y-1)|-\ln|x^{y+1}-1|\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\ln|x| + \ln|x^y-1|-\ln|x^{y+1}-1|\right)
\end{align}
and computing the inside of $\exp$ first. Something like this:

```
z:= ln(abs(x)) + ln(abs(x^y-1)) - ln(abs(x^(y+1)-1))
exp(z)
```

Of course, you have to explicitly take care of the sign of the expression then, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: That just shifts the overflow to inside the logarithm, it does not prevent it any more than the original fraction

Comment: @LutzL Now that I think about it, you're probably correct. My bad, however I did say "may" :P. My answer was mostly to initially just the alternate form of the fraction which was the main question, however I added the second part as something that possibly could help.